# Add roles to user from DMs in new discordjs

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I wanted to know how I could add a role to a specific user within DMs.
With the new Discord.js update, it's tricky, and can't find a way around it.
Thanks.

My attempt:

```
var guild = client.guilds.cache.get("[GUILDID]")
var buyerRole = guild.roles.cache.get("[ROLE ID]")
console.log(message.author.id) // Works
var guildMember = guild.members.fetch(message.author.id)
console.log(guildMember.displayName) // Returns 'undefined'
guildMember.setNickname(guildMember.username+" | Buyer") // Error
console.log(buyerRole.color) // Works
```

Output: `guildMember.setNickname is not a function`

Comment: Can you show your attempt, what part are you stuck on?

Comment: Sure, ill edit it.

Comment: Please show your code as a code block rather than an image. Code blocks can be copied while images cannot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you fetch the member but never await it. `.fetch` returns a promise so the right way to get `guildMember` is like this:

```js
const guildMember = await guild.members.fetch(message.author.id)
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try it, I get "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules"

Comment: Make sure the callback goes like this: `async (message) => {...}`

Comment: I still get it. The async goes with `client.on('messageCreate',async (message)=>{` yeah?

Comment: Oh also, all of this is wrapped in a try method.

Comment: Update your code.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Entire code of your function

Comment: Else use `then`, an alternative of `async`/`await`.

Comment: Oh yeah, I did update the `client.on` event.

Comment: If you are using a .forEach or .then, make sure the callback of that is also async

Comment: Oh, turns out I didn't make `fs.readfile` async. Thanks!